# How can I make a bandaid only cover my fingernail?

Tags: personal-care, comfort

I'm wanting to find out how I can place the bandaid to only cover the finger nail and not the finger tip. If the bandaid is covering my finger tip, it's really hard to use my mac trackpad!!

Any tips?

Comment: Why do you need to cover your nail? I assume you can have it reaching to the side of your finger but not the front?

Comment: I need to keep water off it for a nail treatment! @Lefty

Comment: Usually a "band-aid" (we call them "plasters" where I live) will not keep an area very dry. Some are better than others. However, what I think I might do would be to use surgical tape instead. You could cut a hole in it, as large as you need for your "trackpad area", place some gauze or something over the nail, and loop the tape over the gauze so you have wrapped the end of you finger but with the tip exposed. Would this work?

Comment: @Lefty If you have an answer, please post it below. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I often just cut the Band-Aid to be the size that I need. I'll assume you have a typical Band-Aid, which is a strip of adhesive tape with a square of gauze in the middle.

- Cut off one of the adhesive "legs" just next to the gauze. Set the leg aside to be used later.  Leave the other leg attached to the gauze.
- Cut the gauze to the size you need.
- Trim the attached leg to the size you need.
- Finally, reattach the adhesive leg you cut off initially, and cut that to the size you need.

Apply it to your nail (or, for anyone else reading this, to your cut / wound / blister / whatever).

Answer (score 0):

You are able to buy them in different sizes. They make very small ones that are a lot skinnier than the standard size. They make small round ones as well. If you only have access to the standard ones, they you can split it vertically  to the width you like.